# Two useContexts in a file

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I want to use two useContexts' in the same file.

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react'
import { SubscribeContext } from '../NavBar'
import { AppContext } from '../../../Home'
import './Subscribe.css'

export default function SubscribePopup() {
    const { setSubscribePop } = useContext(SubscribeContext);
    const { error, setError } = useContext(AppContext);
    const [text, setText] = useState("");
    return (
        <div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

SubscribeContext seems to be working fine.
However `useContext(AppContext)` returned undefined

```
#AppContext File
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react'
import Card from './components//Cards/Card'
import NavBar from './components/NavBar/NavBar'


export const AppContext = createContext();
export default function Home() {
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);
    return (
        <div>
            <AppContext.Provider value={{error, setError}}>

            </AppContext.Provider>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Whats wrong here?

Comment: hi, is `SubscribePopup` a child of `AppContext` provider ?

Comment: If it is, then you will have to show the code for AppContext

Comment: I don't think it is. I updated the code

Comment: Have you wrapped `AppContext.Provider` outside of your `SubscribePopup`?

Comment: <SubscribePop/> is used in a different file

Comment: Try creating an initial value for the AppContext. `export const AppContext = createContext({ error: false })`

Comment: HEY! This actually worked. Wasnt expecting that. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating an initial state for **React Context** because without an initial state react context returns undefined.

##### Initial Context

```js
export const AppContext = createContext({ error: false })
```

##### Component

```js
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react'
import Card from './components//Cards/Card'
import NavBar from './components/NavBar/NavBar'

const state = {
  error: false
}

export const AppContext = createContext(state);
export default function Home() {
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);
    return (
        <div>
            <AppContext.Provider value={{error, setError}}>

            </AppContext.Provider>
        </div>
    )
}
export const AppContext = createContext({ error: false })
```